# OpenFileDialog Instantly Closes and Reopens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to update a Jquery Plugin ([simpleCropper](https://github.com/tomazdragar/SimpleCropper)) so that I can dynamically add additional file inputs. I've managed to get it working but with a strange error. To get it working I had to update some of the jquery calls and create a nested destroy function and then reinitiate.

```
cropme.simpleCropper.destroy();
cropme = $('.cropme').simpleCropper();
```

On console.log(cropme); it shows the exact same as before it is destroyed except the new element that's added which is correct.

I can open it fine when the page loads, it works as expected, the problem comes when I open the file dialog after destroying and reinitialising . When the file dialog opens and I select the image it doesn't update the input as expected triggering the file upload, it reopens a new dialog where it then works fine on the second attempt. No console errors appear.

I know it's not triggered because 'change detected' does not show up in the console when it does originally (before destroy) and then on the second attempt.

```
fi.addEventListener("change", function() {
            console.log('change detected');
            imageUpload($(document.getElementById('preview')).get(0));
            // Reset input value
            $(this).val("");
 }, true);
```

Destroy Function:

```
$.fn.simpleCropper.destroy = function(){
        $(document.getElementById('fileInput')).unbind(); //recently added, tried without
        $(document.getElementsByClassName('ok')[0]).unbind(); //recently added, tried without
        $(document.getElementsByClassName('cancel')[0]).unbind(); //recently added, tried without
        $( "#fileInput" ).remove();
        $( "#myCanvas" ).remove();
        $( "#modal" ).remove();
        $( "#preview" ).remove();
        
         reset();
};
```

reset() refers to a function that reset the plugins variables back to default.

What could be causing this behaviour? Thanks